# Is this 'technical' question about syncing on-line content on-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The question [Strategies for keeping multiple platforms in sync?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/1214) is about syncing between social media platforms.

Answers could include not just technical solutions, but also workflows (it *is* asking for 'strategies'), so it is not [strictly technical, and thus off topic](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/should-this-site-cater-to-those-trying-to-build-community-platforms)

[Related meta question](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1351/are-questions-about-managing-virtual-personae-on-topic-here)

Answer (score 4):

I think this is on topic, though does seem to be nudging the "technical" line. You are correct: answers could provide workflows for helping with the problem. However, this is also one of those questions where a little technical detail may improve the answers, as well.

The way that I am reading the question, seems to indicate the user is looking less for that technical solution. I've asked for clarification to be sure though.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is strongly on topic. My take on the discussion on technical aspects in that meta post is more about "rolling your own".  We aren't here to help someone build the tech behind their community, but I don't think that helping figure out how to setup a community with existing tools is particularly off topic.  I think the danger is that we don't want to become "community platform building".

**This site isn't about how to make a new content platform, it's how to manage communities, and part of managing communities is using *existing* technology.**